# show tooltip using layout coordinates

Tags: java, javafx, coordinates

**Basically I want to show a `javafx.scene.control.Tooltip` using screen coordinates.**

In a `Scene` I have a couple of `Node` instances that each have their own `Tooltip` instance. A certain event should trigger all nodes to show their tooltips at the same time. (It's a kind of help feature)

But **the `show` methods use screen coordinates**. So when I use `tooltip.show(node, node.getLayoutX(), node.getLayoutY())` unfortunately all tooltips are off a couple of inches.

Using mouse events, I would have used the `mouseEvent.getScreenX()` and `mouseEvent.getScreenY()` methods to show the tooltip. But unfortunately, **I'm not using the mouse to trigger this event, this time**.

A `Node` doesn't have `getScreenX` methods. So, is there a way **to convert the layout coordinates to screen coordinates ?**

If there is an alternative approach, feel free to share as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to convert directly from layout coordinates to screen coordinates. But there is a method `localToScreen` which can be used to **convert the local coordinates to screen coordinates**.

```
    Bounds bounds = node.localToScreen(getBoundsInLocal());
    tooltip.show(this, bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY());
```